# How to construct multiple dictionaries to array in react native

Tags: arrays, react-native, dictionary, lodash, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to show Expand/Collapse Flatlist data in react-native.
It is like single parent with multiple childs. So, If user tap on the cell, I have to show multiple rows for that expand/collapse.

But, I am getting data from server like following.

```
[{
    code: '1212',
    name: 'Bajaj Model 1',
    url: 'Some url',
    category: 'Bike'
  },
  {
    code: '1213',
    name: 'Bajaj Model 2',
    url: 'other url',
    category: 'Bike'
  },
  {
    code: '1454',
    name: 'BMW Model 1',
    url: 'Some url',
    category: 'Car'
  },
  {
    code: '1454',
    name: 'BMW Model 2',
    url: 'Some url',
    category: 'Car'
  }
]
```

So, All the **Bike** data, I have to show one place like Parent and child.

For that I have done filter.

```
  const fundsFilterData = mapValues(groupBy(response, 'category'),
    fundslist => fundslist.map(item => omit(item, 'category')));
```

And I am getting like following.

```
{
  'Bike': [{
      code: '1212',
      name: 'Bajaj Model 1',
      url: 'Some url'
    },
    {
      code: '1213',
      name: 'Bajaj Model 2',
      url: 'other url'
    },
  ],
  'Car': [{
      code: '1454',
      name: 'BMW Model 1',
      url: 'Some url'
    },
    {
      code: '1454',
      name: 'BMW Model 2',
      url: 'other url'
    },
  ]
}
```

But, I want to make it as array along with some pre added keys like following.

```
[{
    'Title': 'Bike',
    'Values': [{
        'code': '1212',
        'name': 'Bajaj Model 1',
        'url': 'Some url'
      },
      {
        'code': '1454',
        'name': 'Bajaj Model 2',
        'url': 'other url'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'Title': 'Car',
    'Values': [{
        'code": '
        1454 ',
        'name": '
        BMW Model 1 ',
        'url": '
        Some url '
      },
      {
        'code': '1454',
        'name': 'BMW Model 2',
        'url': 'Some url'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So that I can show Titles in headers and once user tap on row, I can show child's data as expanded.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `_.map()` which returns an array, and not `_.mapValues()`. In the `_.map()` get the `Title` (the key) from the 2nd param. Use it and the values (after `_.omit()`) to construct an object for each group.

```js
const { map, groupBy, omit } = _;

const response = [{"code":"1212","name":"Bajaj Model 1","url":"Some url","category":"Bike"},{"code":"1213","name":"Bajaj Model 2","url":"other url","category":"Bike"},{"code":"1454","name":"BMW Model 1","url":"Some url","category":"Car"},{"code":"1454","name":"BMW Model 2","url":"Some url","category":"Car"}];

const fundsFilterData = map(
  groupBy(response, 'category'),
  (list, Title) => ({
    Title,
    Values: list.map(item => omit(item, 'category'))
  })
);

console.log(fundsFilterData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```